# Row deletion not working

Tags: r, row, data-cleaning

I am currently cleaning data and am trying to delete one specific row. I used the `dataset[-row,]` method for other the rows. When I use `dataset[-row,]` for row 3704, it deletes the row two down from it. Any ideas into what is happening and how to delete this row?

Comment: How do you know that you want to delete row 3704? Maybe because of the rowname? If you deleted prior rows, the rownames won't be identical to the row numbers anymore.

Comment: extending on what @Roland said: It would be better to use some unique Variable-value to delete the row since those won't change, i.e.: `dataset <- dataset[dataset$Variable != "Value", ]`